# Sharing image to WhatsApp directly

Tags: ios, share, whatsapp

I want to share image to WhatsApp directly, without showing any intermediate controllers, like UIDocumentInteractionController or UIActivityController.

Official WhatsApp documentation says nothing about direct image sharing, at first glance direct sharing seems impossible.

But I know it's possible. At least 2 apps in App Store can do it:

1. "Sticky AI"
2. WorkFlow https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workflow/id915249334?mt=8

How does Workflow do it? 
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I found something interesting here: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-30-attacking-url-schemes/#gref. 
There is a hint to existence of "whatsapp://image/%@" url scheme.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/i8eqsvET might work. I don't think it's possible to "not" show the action sheet.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/nithinbemitk/iOS-Whatsapp-Share

Comment: @Brandon It's possible. See Workflow or Sticky AI apps.

Comment: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: @Swinny89 Thank you, but I already read this document. There is no answer for my question, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution by LeoNatan@github. Works perfectly.

https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNExtensionExecutor/

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing. I think that's the way to go. I wonder if still works or it's just a problem of mine as the code is a bit old (it's been more than 3 years)
Also, I've been wondering if you had any problems during appstore reviews

Comment: @CihadTurhan do you have a proper solution which you might have added now. I was looking for a recent solution. Please share if you have.

Answer (score -1):

I did this and it works.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image_name"];
NSArray *activityItems = @[image];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewControntroller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewControntroller.excludedActivityTypes = @[];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
{
activityViewControntroller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
activityViewControntroller.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/4, 0, 0);
}
[self presentViewController:activityViewControntroller animated:true completion:nil];
```